# Collect Stats and Explain in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I was asked to run some codes, and " to Collect Stats based on what you see in the subsequent Explain." What does it mean? Thank you.

Comment: You can get the explain plan by using `EXPLAIN` before the query. Example: `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM Emp_Table;`

Answer (score 0):

```
diagnostic helpstats on for session;
explain
<your SQL>;
```

Your collect stats code will be at the bottom of the output.

Comment: The `explain <your SQL>` will give you the detailed execution plan. With `diagnostic helpstats on` you get additional suggestions, which `collect stats` could be helpfull for the optimizer to build a different execution plan. There is no guarantee that collecting stats will result in a better plan, but the probability is high.